# jq implode array of byte integers to raw bytes

Tags: arrays, json, jq, ascii-8bit

With `jq` I have an array of bytes, like `[0, 255, 128, 0, 127]` that I want to convert to a binary file.

It *almost* works like this:

```
jq --raw-output '. | implode' in.json > out.bin
```

But unfortunately it interprets the input as Unicode code points, and writes the result as a UTF-8 string. Is there a binary version of `implode`?

Comment: `jq` is designed to work on text, not binary data. If you need to transfer binary data in a text format, you should use base64 or some other text-based encoding.

Comment: There are many ways to represent binary data in JSON. You don't *have* to use base64. An array of byte values is reasonable too (though not particularly efficient).

Answer (score 1):

jq either produces JSON or (with the -r flag) UTF-8, but you could consider using `iconv` or equivalent, e.g.

```
$ jq -j --raw-output 'implode' <<< '[0, 255, 128, 40, 127]'  | iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ISO-8859-16
```

The output apparently cannot be shown here, so consider instead:

```
$ jq -j --raw-output 'implode' <<< '[0, 255, 128, 40, 127]'  | iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ISO-8859-16 | xxd -ps
00ff80287f

$ jq -j --raw-output 'implode' <<< '[0, 255, 128, 40, 127]'  | xxd -ps
00c3bfc280287f
```

In any case, note that 
the initial `.|` is unnecessary.

Comment: That is pretty ugly. Not sure I can bring myself to use it! Does work though.

Comment: Is `perl -MEncode -E 'print decode_utf8(<STDIN>)'` less ugly?

Comment: No I mean the ugliness is that you are encoding a byte stream as UTF-8 only to decode it again. I had a look into the `jq` source code though and unfortunately everything is based around JSON data types. There's no "byte array" in JSON so it isn't trivial to add a `binary_implode` function.

Comment: I think the point is that it would not be possible without breaking jq. Or in other words, the j in jq stands for JSON.